# Simple Question: convert a string to an image tag in c# asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I used a generic image handler to handle image

```
<td width="100px"><%:MyImageHandler.CreateImage(item.PictureId, 100).ToString()%></td>
```

and the generic handler should return a string like

<img src='/Photo/MyImageHandler.ashx?id=9&size=100'/>

I am exhausted to output a string in the form of a image tag
I tried the string builder and other string constructor and it only return :

```
&lt;img src='/Photo/MyImageHandler.ashx?id=9&amp;size=100'/&gt;
```

rather than
<img src='/Photo/MyImageHandler.ashx?id=9&size=100'/>

Do you have any suggestions on that? I really need your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:` will automatically encode your string which is why your `<` is getting turned into a `&lt;`

You have 2 options

1. return a `MvcHtmlString` instead of a string in the method `createImage`
2. use `<%=` instead of `<%:`

You would use an MvcHtmlString if you want to return raw HTML from an MVC helper method.

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help